# Building a Language Model Using Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: python-2.7, recurrent-neural-network

I get this error when I run my code.

***Exception: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 12196 input samples and 1 target samples.***

Below is the model I train.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

n_in = x_train.shape[1]
n_hidden = 100
n_out = word_vecs.shape[0]
number_of_epochs = 10
batch_size = 35

model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(output_dim=word_vecs.shape[1],                 input_dim=word_vecs.shape[0],input_length=n_in,  weights=[word_vecs],  mask_zero=True))  

model.add(LSTM(n_hidden, W_regularizer=l2(0.0001), U_regularizer=l2(0.0001), return_sequences=True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_out, activation='softmax', W_regularizer=l2(0.0001))))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

I also encoded a one hot vector of my train data.

below is the code

```
new_instance = []

for instance in train_y :
    new_vector = np.zeros(shape=(instance.shape[0],  word_vecs.shape[0]))

    print(instance.shape[0],  word_vecs.shape[0])

    new_vector[np.arange(new_vector.shape[0]), instance ] =1

new_instance.append(new_vector)
new_instance = np.array(new_instance)
```

and this is my output for the one hot vector

```
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)
(260, 4075)

[[[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  ..., 
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]]
```

and finally

```
for epoch in range(number_of_epochs):    
        start_time = time.time()

        #Train for 1 epoch
        model.fit(train_x, new_instance, nb_epoch=1,  batch_size=batch_size, verbose=False, shuffle=True)   

        print("%.2f sec for training" % (time.time() - start_time))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am new to this, plese pardon me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After sometime I found out the problem was wrong indentation in a one hot vector encoding code. Also I reduced the size of my dataset Size to make it comply faster.

below is the corrected code

```
new_instance = []

for instance in train_y :
    new_vector = np.zeros(shape=(instance.shape[0],  word_vecs.shape[0]))

    print(instance.shape[0],  word_vecs.shape[0])

    new_vector[np.arange(new_vector.shape[0]), instance ] =1

    new_instance.append(new_vector)
new_instance = np.array(new_instance)
```